# How can I align a radio button's text under the button itself

Tags: html, css

I would like to have five radio buttons next to each other and have each one's text centered beneath its button. It should look like this:

```
     *     *     *     *     *
   Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4 Text5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it would help if you played around with it, but this is the way that I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAfTy/2/

```
<div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />title 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />title 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />title 3</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />title 4</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="radioset" />title 5</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio] {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Basically, the radio button takes the entire width of the parent, and the labels are aligned `inline-block` to each other.

Comment: beat me to it! although make sure you include IE7 and below backfill for `display:inline-block;`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea unless he specifically needs IE7, there's no point haha. No need to support IE7 unless it's necessary.

Comment: eh why not, when its so easy and doesn't impact anything else? gotta snatch that low-hanging fruit when ya can ;)

Comment: Well, for one, Windows XP is soon to be deprecated, which should include at least IE7, and I think IE8. But also, according to w3schools browser demographics, IE7 takes up a whopping .4% of total users. Supporting IE7 is more work than it's worth. Yes, this one is easy, but all in all, IE7 is not, and definitely not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is html / css example to do what you want i think.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="">
    <div class="radio-box">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><label>Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-box">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><label>Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-box">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><label>Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-box">
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"><label>Male</label>
    </div>         
</form>
```

**CSS :**

```
form {
    width: 100%;
}
div.radio-box {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.radio-box label {
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.radio-box input {
    width: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

you can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/E4FPu/1/

Answer (score 1):

css code

```
 <style type="text/css">
        tr { text-align:center }
 </style>
```

and html code :

```
 <table>
     <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="option_a" id="option_a"><br /><label for="option_a">Option A</label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="option_b" id="option_b"><br /><label for="option_b">Option B</label></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="option_c" id="option_c"><br /><label for="option_c">Option C</label></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Should not be using TABLES for laying things out

Answer (score 1):

Since someone already recommended a table, figured I'd offer something else:

CSS:

```
.radioLabel {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;

    /* IE 7 and below */
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}

.radioLabel * {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label class="radioLabel">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" />
    <span class="radioSpan">Text1</span>
</label><label class="radioLabel">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" />
    <span class="radioSpan">Text2</span>
</label><label class="radioLabel">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" />
    <span class="radioSpan">Text3</span>
</label><label class="radioLabel">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" />
    <span class="radioSpan">Text4</span>
</label><label class="radioLabel">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSet" />
    <span class="radioSpan">Text5</span>
</label>
```

Now if you click anywhere over the label the radio will activate, much more button-like.